# Pass dictionary object to function as thread, not its values

Tags: python, multithreading, function, dictionary

I have a script, which runs a function as a thread. The function works with the contents of a dictionary from the main, but does not need to alter it.

For example

```
from threading import Thread

def a_func(self, dic):
    print(str(dic))

some_dic={
    1:"A",
    2:"B"
}

print(str(some_dic))

t = Thread(target=a_func, args=(some_dic))
t.start()
```

The resulting output is:

```
{1: 'A', 2: 'B'}
2
```

I've read that the first argument passed to a threaded function is itself - did I misunderstand that?

Even without the issues with `self`, the function does not print the actual dictionary object, rather the key in this case.

How do I pass the dictionary object to the threaded function, resulting in the output:

```
{1: 'A', 2: 'B'}
{1: 'A', 2: 'B'}
```

Comment: Were you trying to pass a *tuple* of arguments? Try `..., args=(some_dic,))`

Comment: that results in the exact same output..

Comment: Sorry I missed out a parenthesis. I've clarified, try that; note the trailing comma which makes it a tuple.

Comment: If i do that and remove the `self` from the expected parameters in the function it works as intended! thank you! If you form an answer of the comments, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

args is supposed to be a tuple of all the arguments to the function, so to pass a dictionary, you need a tuple of a dictionary.

In addition, Python requires you to add the extra comma for a tuple with one element to differentiate it from just wrapping an expression with parentheses.

In addition, why are you using self in the function ?
This code should work :

```
from threading import Thread

def a_func(dic):
    print dic

some_dic={
    1:"A",
    2:"B"
}

print(str(some_dic))

t = Thread(target=a_func, args=(some_dic,))
t.start()
```